# Can you load Google Maps API v3 via Google AJAX API loader

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2, google-ajax-api

Some time ago I used the regular method of loading Google Maps API like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=abcdefg&sensor=true">
```

Later I switched to Google AJAX APIs to load Google Maps API. This was because a couple of "widgets" on my website needed the Google Ajax API loader so I chose to be consistent and used the AJAX APIs to load Google Maps as well:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=abcdef"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("maps", "2", {"other_params": "sensor=true"});
</script>
```

Now that I have finally decided to use Google Maps API v3, [this page](http://code.google.com/apis/loader/index.html#AvailableAPIs) does not list API v3 in the available version list. None of the examples on API v3 documentation show the use of AJAX APIs as well. Is is possible (and supported) to load Google Maps API v3 via AJAX API loader?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's undocumented, but it works.

```
google.load("maps", "3", {other_params:'key=YOUR_API_KEY', callback: function(){
  var map; // initialize your map in here
}});
```

[EDIT]
The documentation now requires the use of an API key that is passed to the loader as a "key" parameter. I've removed 'sensor=false' as a parameter because it is now explicitly not required and throws a warning when provided.

Comment: Does "undocumented" mean it may (not) work as expected or it may (not) work in the future?

Comment: @Salman Well, turns out it's [documented](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#loadasync), just hidden deep inside the FAQ, rather than the documentation.

Comment: Right... seems like v3 api still has a long way to go.

Comment: This is a great answer! Just wanted to let you know you're missing a } at the end. You need to close the callback function and the .load function.
`}});`

Comment: Just to add clarification to how the call would look if you setup your map in a separate function:    google.load('maps', '3', {other_params:'sensor=true', "callback" : yourFunctionName});

Comment: how do you add your API key? i keep getting this warning on firebug `Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
util.js (line 210)`

Comment: @user2636556 I have updated the answer to address this issue.

Answer (score -1):

this example work perfectly.

```
//Set google Api
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
//Initialize General
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Add Jquery, if you need
    google.load("jquery", "1.7.1");
    //Initialize Map, with option sensor=false
    google.load("maps", 3, {other_params:"key=YOUR_API_KEY"});
    //Initialize Map's
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
            var options = {
                  zoom: 10,
                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.616507,-58.409463),
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), options);
    });


</script>
```

Comment: I've updated this answer with currently working code. Love it when Google changes things without warning.